# Xcode 6.2 to 6.4 update failed

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore

I waited for about 8 hours to finish my 2.6 GB download to update from Xcode 6.2 to 6.4. After waiting it says it is installed. Opening Xcode it prompted me to install additional files and I accepted it. Once the installation was finished, it still says that my version is 6.2. After restarting my Mac Mini it still says that my Xcode version is 6.2. I checked App store, and Xcode still wants to update to 6.4. Whereas my "Updates installed in the Last 30 Days" tab it indicates that I was done downloading the 6.4 version.

How can I update my Xcode 6.2 to 6.4?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the standard "first fix" tasks.

- Disk Utility, Repair Permissions, then Verify & if necessary Repair Disk.
- Apply or re-apply the latest combo updater - [10.10.5 here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832). This can fix many odd issues.